# ZedGraph Horizontal threshold line issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, zedgraph

I'm in a trouble, while drawing a horizontal line in ZedGraph, it's always starting from 1st position, but I want to start it from 0th position. I'm using the following code

```
double[] x = {100,100,100,100 };    
LineItem myCurve = pane.AddCurve( "My Curve",
                null,x, Color.Red, SymbolType.Diamond );
```

I'm using old version of ZedGraph, that is another headache. 
Please help me to solve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
 double threshHoldY = 2;
    LineObj threshHoldLine = new LineObj(
        Color.Red,
        graphPane.XAxis.Scale.Min,
        threshHoldY,
        graphPane.XAxis.Scale.Max,
        threshHoldY);
    graphPane.GraphObjList.Add(threshHoldLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use LineObj.

```
LineObj line = new LineObj(Color.Red, 
                   myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min, 100, myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max, 100);
line.Location.CoordinateFrame = CoordType.AxisXYScale;   
line.Location.AlignH = AlignH.Left;
line.Location.AlignV = AlignV.Top;   
line.ZOrder = ZOrder.E_BehindAxis;
myPane.GraphObjList.Add(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you cannot just put a horizontal line on the bar graph because the x-axis type for this case is not numeric/discrete - it is a Text value.

If you want to put horizontal lines on your bar charts you have to use the combo chart: http://zedgraph.dariowiz.com/indexd6f1.html?title=Combo_Chart_Demo

This way the x-axis is numeric so you can create any lines you need along with the bars.

Here is sample code for such a line:

```
        double[] x5 = { 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1200 };
        double[] y5 = { 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70 };

        // Generate a black line with "Curve 4" in the legend
        LineItem myCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Curve 4",
        x5, y5, Color.Black, SymbolType.None);
        myCurve.Line.Width = 3.0F;
```